# Azure function is not sending data to Azure signlR

Tags: javascript, azure, signalr, azure-functions, serverless-framework

I have Timer trigger Azure function which calls API and send output data to signalR. Also I have already setup the AzureSignalRConnectionString in Application Setting. But issue is *Azure SignalR does not show any activity in connection metrics*.

[image]

**Azure Function:**

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

module.exports = async function (context) {

    let response = await fetch('<ENDPOINT>');
    let data = await response.json();

    context.bindings.signalRMessages = [{
        "target": "latestData",
        "arguments": [data]
    }];
    context.log('Done');
};
```

**function.json**

```
{
  "bindings": [

  {
    "name": "myTimer",
    "type": "timerTrigger",
    "direction": "in",
    "schedule": "*/5 * * * * *"
  },
  {
    "type": "signalR",
    "name": "signalRMessages",
    "hubName": "health",
    "direction": "out"
  }

  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the official doc, the signalr connection string needs to be on the binding schema:

```
{
  "type": "signalR",
  "name": "signalRMessages", // name of the output binding
  "hubName": "<hub_name>",
  "connectionStringSetting": "<setting_name>", // Defaults to AzureSignalRConnectionString
  "direction": "out"
}
```

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-signalrservice-extension

Define the SignalR Setting using the following AZ CLI Command:

```
#========================================================================
#=== Update these variables for your resources.                       ===
#========================================================================
ResourceGroupName=SignalRTestResources
SignalRServiceResource=mySignalRresourcename
WebAppName=myWebAppName

# Get the SignalR primary connection string 
primaryConnectionString=$(az signalr key list --name $SignalRServiceResource \
  --resource-group $ResourceGroupName --query primaryConnectionString -o tsv)

#Add an app setting to the web app for the SignalR connection
az webapp config appsettings set --name $WebAppName \
    --resource-group $ResourceGroupName \
    --settings "Azure__SignalR__ConnectionString=$primaryConnectionString"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-authenticate-oauth

Comment: I already tried that, but it's giving error--- "Unable to resolve the value for property 'SignalRAttribute.ConnectionStringSetting'. Make sure the setting exists and has a valid value." Also I've copied same connection string ("Endpoint=https://<NAME>.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=<ACCESS_KEY>;Version=1.0;") from SignalR, but still it is giving error..

Comment: you should give "AzureSignalRConnectionString" as the value. Then in the app Settings, create a settign with this name and the value will be the signalr connection string:  Endpoint=<service_endpoint>;AccessKey=<access_key>;

Comment: I gave input as you suggested but no luck.... "ConnectionStringSetting" : "AzureSignalRConnectionString"